# Not able to connect JDBC with SQL Server

Tags: java, jdbc

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class JdbcSQLServerConnection {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {



            Connection conn = null;
            try {


              String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://microsoft\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=crud";
              String userName = "sa";
              String password = "pwd";
              System.out.println("Connected2");
              Class.forName("com.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);


                System.out.println("Connected");
                if (conn != null) {
                    DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                    System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                    System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                    System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                    System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                        conn.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

output:-

```
Connected2 Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at JdbcSQLServerConnection.main(JdbcSQLServerConnection.java:28)
```

I have included sqljdbc4.jar in eclipse library but still it is not
working  on my system please help me in this solution`enter code here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot reference jdbc.SQLServerDriver in Eclipse (ClassNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834515/cannot-reference-jdbc-sqlserverdriver-in-eclipse-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: How to solve this really depends on your "project type." For example, if you're using a Maven or Gradle project you can use it to resolve the dependency by using groupId com.microsoft.sqlserver, artifactId sqljdbc4, and version 4.0.

Comment: The name of the driver is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`, not `com.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the class you try to load (`com.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`) is not found.

According to [Microsoft Docs "Using the JDBC Driver"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect) you have to load the JDBC-Driver by calling `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` -- note the `microsoft` between `com` and `sqlserver`

If this does not help, you might want to

1. Compile your code and run it on the command line, manually adding the JDBC driver JAR to the classpath (`-cp`) to get rid of any pitfall in Eclipse.
2. Rename the `sqljdbc4.jar` to `sqljdbc4.zip`, unzip it and check whether the class you try to load really exists in there...

Comment: I have changed class in my project, still my program is showing same error as before.
I have checked the files in sqljdbc4 and class is available in it which i want to use.

Comment: So you corrected the class name in the code by adding the missing "microsoft"? Then I'd check whether the class is really on the classpath. You say you added the library to Eclipse - did you either add it to the build path or the classpath of the run configuration? Just adding the file itself does not add it to the classpath... If you try to run your program on the command line, you'll see whether this is a problem with the project setup in Eclipse or a java problem.